# How to re run java code after user inputs data

Tags: java

Hey I have a basic java 'app' showing if people are an adult or teen etc.. I am starting out with java and I can't find how to make it so after a user has input an age, and the string of what they are classified as shows I would like it to re run the whole thing again so someone else can have a go. I have been looking into doing a loop but that hasn't worke dout for me.. Here is the code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Declare local variables
    int age;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Prompt user for Age
    System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
    age = in.nextInt();

    if(age > 17)
    {
        System.out.println("This persons age indicates that they an adult");
    }
    else if (age > 12)
    {
        System.out.println("This persons age indicates that they are a teenager");
    }
    else if (age >= 0)
    {
        System.out.println("This persons age indicates that they are a child");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("That age is invalid");
    }

    //Close input
    in.close();
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am sure it is super simple and I have missed something.

Comment: What did you try with the loops?

Comment: Put all the content of `main` into a separate method and call it as many times as you wish.

Comment: @allieluu This code should be refactored - and you suggest to add more complexity into it instead...

Comment: @alfasin I only wanted to clarify what specifically he tried. If it was something as simple as not putting all of the necessary code in the loop, I would be able to help better. It wasn't intended to be a suggestion yet.

Comment: Also, don't close `in` here, because that closes `System.in`. (Sometimes you need to close streams, and sometimes you don't. You should close a lot of things, but not System.in)

Answer (score 2):

You can put it in a loop such as

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Declare local variables
    int age;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(true){
    //Prompt user for Age
    System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
        age = in.nextInt();

        if(age > 17)
        {
            System.out.println("This persons age indicates that they an adult");
        }
        else if (age > 12)
        {
            System.out.println("This persons age indicates that they are a teenager");
        }
        else if (age >= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("This persons age indicates that they are a child");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("That age is invalid");
        }
}

        //Close input
        in.close(); //Note that this happens outside the loop
    }
```

or put the needed code in a method

```
public static void ageCheck()
{
  //code that is currently in main method
}
```

it would be called from the main method by

```
this.ageCheck();
```

Comment: You might need the code "in.nextLine()" at the end of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a   while(true) loop to run forever

Answer (score 0):

You can call your `main()` recursively

After this `in.close();`statement just call your `main()` like this

```
 in.close();
  main(null);
```

But you must put some conditions when to stop the execution of you program.